# Javascript line graph with tics and difference bar

Tags: javascript

[image: chart]

I'm trying to create a chart similar to the one on the link in JavaScript (going to have the chart in Design Studio). I need there to be a line chart with the current years data and tick marks under with last years data. Between the line chart and the tick I want a bar connecting the two.

I've tried several things but I can only get somewhat close. Due to a few outliers, I also need to keep all values above a certain value and below a certain value to stay in a certain range to avoid the plummets seen.

This graph was created in Excel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)